# An old cartoon about an astronaut who lands on a planet, fights dinosaur-like aliens, then dies at sun down

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon, astronauts

I found this single video, but someone has overdubbed it with music from No Man's Sky and possibly appears to have altered the title in the video. I can't find reference to it anywhere using any sort of description of its contents.

I'm interested in the true video source as I love the look of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen this animation before, but Google's reverse image search was able to identify it as a Soviet short film called [*Хозяева Геоны*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B), released in 1991 or 1992.

Comment: Well done, thank you.